# How to pass a value from parent to a fancybox 2.1.7 element, afterShow?

Tags: parameter-passing, fancybox-2

```
$.fancybox({
  type: 'iframe',
  href: url,
  afterShow:  function() {
    var name = parent.$('#pname').val();
    $('#fname').val(name);
    $('#fname').focus();
    return true;
  },
  beforeClose: function(){
     clsCarr();
  },
```

Where `pname` is an input box in the parent document and fname is an input box in the fancybox document.  How to I put the value of `pname` in to `fname`?  `afterShow` knows the value of `pname`, but is not putting it in `fname`.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that this is an `iframe` in the fancybox.  It's always interesting trying to get iframes to "talk" with their parent document, so I'm not positive I've got this 100% right.  :)

```
var name = parent.getElementById("lst-ib").value;
document.querySelector("#fancybox-content iframe").contentDocument.getElementById("fname").value = name;
```

My thought behind this is that probably your `$.fancybox` is running in your parent document, and when you use `parent.$('#pname').val()` it would be equivalent to running `$('#pname').val()`, since parent will not be able to be any 'higher' than the root document.

Thus, if my theory is correct, you will need to get the `iframe` and access its `contentDocument` (or perhaps just `document`), and fetch the ID of the element inside the iframe.

This would, obviously, only work if the `iframe` is using the same domain as your parent document.  I believe browsers implement some sort of cross-domain verification nowadays.

Comment: The parent.$('#pname').val() is working. It gets the value of pname in the parent document. But I can't seem to get the name in the fname field of the document opened in the fancybox. The fancybox document is created with an ajax call.

Comment: Right, I just noticed that it's an iframe ?  I've updated my answer - but I'm not 100% certain it's correct.  Is the website online somewhere that you could share ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just can't get this to work.   I get the parent name but can't get it into the fancybox iframe name.  Don't Know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you know how to use console.log and the Chrome / Firefox web inspector ?  To open it in Chrome, use `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`J`.  Click your fancybox link and then paste this code into the console and press `ENTER`.  `document.querySelector("#fancybox-content iframe").contentDocument.getElementById("fname").value`.  Paste the output here.